# Use of ROW() or COLUMN() in OFFSET(...) generating #N/A! error

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I want to have a cell at the top of a column of data which uses a worksheet function to record the total number of cells below it which contain data. There are no gaps in the column, so I figure I don’t need to use COUNTA, it would be more efficient to find the first blank cell. To this end I have the following function in cell R12:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(OFFSET($R$12,1,0,1000,1)),0),0)-1
```

This worked fine until I tried to use a named reference cell to define the resized range a bit more flexibly… replacing  the above with

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(OFFSET($R$12,1,0,ROW(last_cell)-ROW(),1)),0),0)-1
```

gives `#N/A!` in the cell. As a formula `=ROW(last_cell)-ROW()` works fine on its own so it’s a puzzle to me why it doesn’t work in the compound formula… even replacing a 1 in the OFFSET parameters with `ROW(A1)` throws an error.

I can work round it, but this behaviour is really annoying! Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Go to your cell. Select Formula Ribbon -> Formula Auditing -> Evaluate formula. Walk it through 1 step at a time. What does each term evaluate as? You appear to expect Row(last_cell)-Row() to = 1,000. Does it? Does it maybe equal a negative number? What is last_cell? Go to your Name Manager and confirm that it refers to the range you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) is expecting a long integer as its *[height]* parameter and you are shoving an array of integers at it. Yes, there is only one integer in the array but it is still an array and OFFSET is jumping ship at the first sign of potential trouble. If you evaluate the formula as suggested by Grade 'Eh' Bacon above, you will see that the result of that simple math subtraction is wrapped in *braces* (e.g. **{** and **}** ). You need to remove any indication that the *[height]* parameter is being fed an array or OFFSET will keep choking.

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(OFFSET($R$12, 1, 0, MIN(ROW(last_cell)-ROW()), 1)),0),0)-1
```

There are any number of basic Excel worksheet functions that can take an array of 1 and turn it into an integer. I've used the [MIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7). [MAX](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333), [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57), [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6), etc. would all work. They take an array of numbers and return a single integer, even if that array of numbers has only one number.

On a related topic, I find it admirable that you are trying to reduce the calculation cycles in your workbook but you are missing one important consideration. The first thing you should do is throw out the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) altogether.

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK($R$12:INDEX($R:$R, ROW(last_cell)+1)), , ), 0)-1
```

OFFSET is a volatile formula that recalculates whenever *anything* in the workbook changes. Opting for the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) equivalent takes the formula out of volatile mode and it will only recalculate when something that affects its outcome changes.

You may be interested in the way OFFSET erroneously treats floating point errors. See [OFFSET_Floating_Point_Error](https://docs.com/jeeped-tj/4358/offset-floating-point-error) for more on that.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped & Grade 'Eh' Bacon... sorry for late reply as I went home in frustration straight after posting... I was vaguely aware that i should try to avoid OFFSET but hadn't looked into it... the type mismatch idea makes a lot of sense, I will try out the alternatives tonight

Answer (score 0):

Having had a chance to play around a bit, I'm still confused!

OFFSET itself doesn't seem to have a problem accepting the return values of ROW and COLUMN as parameters. To use a trivial example, this formula works:

=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET($R$12,ROW(1)+1,0,ROW(R20)-COLUMN(),1))

Trying different ways of eliminating OFFSET from the expression, I came up with:

=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(13,18)&":"&ADDRESS(1012,18))),0),0)-1

Which works, at the cost of swapping OFFSET for INDIRECT (which I'm hoping is the lesser of 2 evils!) However I would prefer to use:

=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(last_cell),COLUMN()))),0),0)-1

Which doesn't work, giving #N/A! again, as does changing any of the explicit integers to ROW or COLUMN expressions.

Individually, I've tried OFFSET, INDEX, ISBLANK and MATCH with ROW and COLUMN expressions and they all seem to work, so it seems to be something about using them in compound formulae which is throwing the error.